# Check if macro is already defined

Tags: macros, conditionals

How can I check if a macro is already defined? I want to make a command `\dd`. However, if the `physics` package is loaded I need to do `\renewcommand` and if it is not loaded I need to do `\newcommand`. So I want some sort of way to check if the macro `\dd` is defined or not.

Here is some pseudocode which showes what I want:

```
if <\dd> is defined:
    \renewcommand ....
else:
     \newcommand ...
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{physics} % may or may not be loaded

% Definition of \dd
% \newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}
% or
% \renewcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}

\begin{document}

Hello $\dd f$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\providecommand{\dd}{}\renewcommand{\dd}{<what you want>}`

Comment: if you want to define `\dd` as `\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}` in both cases, you don't have to check whether it's defined, you can just use `\def\dd{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question in the first sentence, "How can I check if a macro is already defined?":

```
\ifdefined\dd
    %% it is already defined
\else
    %% it is not yet defined
\fi
```

I actually use this a lot, e.g., as a boolean switch (which I can switch on with `\def\myswitch{}` and switch off with `\let\myswitch\undefined`).

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to do

```
\def\dd{<whatever you like>}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to do

```
\providecommand{\dd}{}% defines \dd if not already defined
\renewcommand{\dd}{<whatever you like>}
```

If it's for your personal use, fine.

*Don't* do it in a package code. A user loading your package might want to use `\dd` from `physics` (I wouldn't, but people seem to like packages that promise much more than they can actually offer).

<sub>I don't like `physics`: it's badly written and has really weird syntax.</sub>

Comment: Also, I found that it was defined somewhere else, using ``\DeclareRobustCommand``. I guess this also works.

Comment: @Vebjorn Be careful, because `\DeclareRobustCommand` doeno check. In this case, no problem, becayiu do want to redefine anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the command `\ifcsdef` from `etoolbox` works like this. It can check whether a macro is defined or not, and executes some code. Here is how it works:

```
\ifcsdef{<macro>}
    {<true code>}
    {<false code>}
```

If the macro is defined, `<true code>` is executed, and if not, `<false code>` is executed. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{physics} % may or may not be loaded

\makeatletter
\ifcsdef{dd}
    {\renewcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}}
    {\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello $\dd f$

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is not a lot of point using `\renewcommand` here as its only function is to warn of redefinition which you are subverting anyway. `\let\dd\relax\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}` is simpler and does not require any test or duplicated code

Comment: `\ifcsdef` is available as `\@ifundefined` in core latex with no package needed (just true and false branches reversed)

Comment: If you really want to do a test, how about `\ifcsdef{dd}{\renewcommand}{\newcommand}*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}`

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I found this solution:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dd}{\relax\ifmmode\ddaux\relax\fi}
\newcommand*{\ddaux}{\mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}}
\makeatother
```

Which 1) overwrites `\dd` from the physics package *if* it is imported, and 2) ensures that the command only works in mathmode.